# Collect ajax errors?

Tags: ajax

Is there any best practice for collecting AJAX errors? Some of my webpages are using jQuery AJAX calls to my server, while I can capture errors on my server side, I believe the client side must have errors too. I hope to capture those errors at client side as well, and send the error report to a server, so I can know the detail information of client side browser type, their cookies setting, the original url, etc.

I did some search, and found that Sentry provide a Raven-js can do this kind of things, but as Sentry is a paid service, is there any open source or free solutions? Thank you!

---

Update: It's 2018, any Javascript solution to this question? Thanks!